# Stats Puzzle About Random Guesses

Tags: random-variable, standard-deviation, puzzle

If you are told to guess a number between 1 and 100 that is as close as possible to the standard deviation of the guesses of others who are told the same thing, what number would you guess?

Comment: *"as close as possible to the standard deviation of the guesses of others"* what does that mean? Say, if the others all guess 50 then the sd of theif guesses is equal to zero, then should I guess zero which is equal to the standard deviation, or should I guess 50 which is within the range of the mean of the guesses of the others plusminus a standard deviation?

Comment: What do we know about the guesses of the others? Did they get the same question or something different? Should we assume some logical thinking? What is the goal of the guess, is there a prize to win or something to loose, is this some [coordination game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordination_game)? *(part of the problem is that there is no single as close as possible, but rather there is a range of close as possible with different probabilities, and you need a [cost/loss function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_function) to optimize your choice)*

Comment: This is really a question about [Nash equilibrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_equilibrium).

Comment: Since 0 is not an allowable guess, the Nash equilibrium in this case is to guess 1 (with probability one).  Assuming each player plays the Nash equilibrium, the true standard deviation of the guesses is zero, and so everyone "over-guesses" by one.